# SVN to Git: Extracting part of a repository

Tags: git, svn

I am working on converting an SVN repo into a handful of git repos using the documentation at https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/import/svn.html - which specifies using this https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git tool.

My basic goal is to have one git repo that mirrors the original SVN repo. This repo will serve primarily as a historical record. I then want to move some of the subdirectories in the SVN repo into their own git repos.

I am doing this with the below script:

```
#!/bin/sh

mkdir repo.git
pushd repo.git
git config --global gc.auto 0
svn2git svn+ssh://svnhost/svn/dvl/svn/repo --authors ~/authors.txt
git gc
git config --global unset gc.auto
popd

pushd repo.git
git subtree split -P subdir/project/ -b project-subtree
popd

mkdir project.git
pushd project.git
git init
git pull ../repo.git project-subtree
popd
```

`repo.git` has the branches and tags I'd expect, but `project.git` does not have any of those. Is there a way to get the branches and tags into `project.git`? If not, what is the "right" way to do this?

I have also tried

```
svn2git svn+ssh://svnhost/svn/dvl/svn/repo/subdir/project --authors ~/authors.txt --no-minimize-url
```

But that produces an empty repo as it looks for `svn+ssh://svnhost/svn/dvl/svn/repo/subdir/project/trunk`. Adding `--rootistrunk` to the above command produces an error.

Answer (score 1):

## git filter-branch

after you have converted the repo from svn to git, you should be able to extract one subdir as a stand alone git repo with the command:

```
git filter-branch --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter subdir -- --all
```

be careful that it works locally transforming your repo (so it is better to work on a copy)...
the old master (and similarly others branch) is however temporarily reachable with refs/original/refs/heads/master
so that you can recover it...

after you checked that it is all ok, you can delete it following the [instructions](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch#_checklist_for_shrinking_a_repository), in particular:

```
git for-each-ref --format="%(refname)" refs/original/ | xargs -n 1 git update-ref -d
```